# How can i return only few values from an array

Tags: c++

I have a array of floats i need to return only the position values from the array as std::vector, which are the first three values.

Currently i am not able to figure out how can i do that.

```
 float vertices[] = {
// positions          // normals           // texture coords
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,

-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,

-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
-0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f
};
```

Comment: Return the entire array (it's not gonna cost you any more than "returning just those values"), then simply ignore the other values.

Comment: Just to clarify do you want to return the 3 dimensional position values for all points or just the first point?

Comment: @PeteBlackerThe3rd i want to return from all the points.

Comment: you need to know the number of the elements `vertices` table

Comment: @Raffalo Yes i would know the number of elements before hand.

Comment: I would not be storing these in a `std::vector<float>`. It would be more appropriate to store then in something like `std::vector<float[3]>`

Comment: Learn to use [C++ standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). Your above code is not genuine C++

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 A fixed size array *is* a data structure. What makes you think it isn’t appropriate? `struct { float x; float y; float z; }` just adds abstraction.

Comment: _"Currently i am not able to figure out how can i do that"_ isn't really a very good problem statement. Did you try anything? Read anything? Go further, push harder.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits uff sorry I misread your comment and thought you are refering to the float array posted in the question (not the one that should be extracted). Sorry for the superflous comment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like that

```cpp
std::vector<float> getPositions(int nentries, const float *data)
{
    std::vector<float> positions;
    positions.reserve(nentries*3);

    for (int i = 0; i < nentries; ++i)
    {
        positions.push_back(data[8*i + 0];
        positions.push_back(data[8*i + 1];
        positions.push_back(data[8*i + 2];
    }
    return positions;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do it. There are 8 elements per vertex in your array, so you can use a for loop with a stride of 8 to iterate once for each vertex. Then you can copy each position dimension out into a std::vector.

```
int arrayLength = <assume you have this value somewhere>;

std::vector<float> points;

for (int p=0; p<arrayLength; p+=8)
{
  points.push_back(vertices[p]);
  points.push_back(vertices[p+1]);
  points.push_back(vertices[p+2]);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to `reserve`.

Comment: I like the for loop in this answer better than the accepted one. What is being iterated is much more clearly expressed.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct vertex
{
    static const size_t number_of_floats = 3;

    float x, y, z;
};

std::vector<vertex> get_vertices(const float *data, const size_t data_count, const size_t vals_per_row = 8)
{
    std::vector<vertex> vertices;
    vertices.reserve(data_count/vals_per_row + (data_count % vals_per_row == 0 ? 0 : 1); 

    for (size_t pos = 0; pos+vertex::number_of_floats <= data_count; pos += vals_per_row)
    {
        vertices.push_back({data[pos], data[pos+1], data[pos+2]});
    } 

    return vertices;
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right. Fixed it a little. Will work on a better generic version.